# How does the wand affect skills which has elemental damage?

Tags: torchlight-2

I play Embermage, example, Inferno skill tree, some skills have something like "X fire damage over 6s". Do these things affect to that ?

- Fire wand ( with high fire damage )
- The bonus: +Y% fire damage

Answer (score 2):

The wand's damage will not affect skills that do not use weapon DPS. Ex. Magma Spear's "6 Fire Damage over 3 seconds" is not affected by your wands fire damage, but the "XX% of Weapon DPS as Fire" *is* affected by your wands high damage.

Passive Damage bonuses like "+Y% Fire Damage" apply to all skills that deal fire damage whether they use weapon DPS or not.

Skill damage is also affected by bonuses from stats and armor enchants.